# How to remove bottom line from nav-tab in bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In my menu when you select an item in my vertical nav you can see a little border below of the item `HERE`, how can I delete that border?
I tried this but didn't work too

```css
.nav-tabs li, .nav-tabs li a {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Picture of the border

https://www.screencast.com/t/BWNUP1n3

Comment: where is the border? ı can not see

Comment: @CanUver See my updated question I put a picture of the border

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `box-shadow` from class `main-purple`

```
.main-purple {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the class on the main ul element like

> tab-button

than style it

```
.tab-buttons {border-bottom: 0px !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is within #vertical-nav
if you remove all box-shadow it will remove your "border" under HERE

**EDIT**: After seeing the screenshot yes just replace the #vertical-nav with this:

```
#vertical-nav {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0; 
    color: #fff;
}
```